# Is there a way to add background properties using CSS to a gradient with an image as background?

Tags: css

I have CSS which I am adding a gradient to an Image. It is adding the gradient successfully but the background Image is repeating. I want to set it to cover the whole body and center it and have a no-repeat properties. How can I achieve this? I tried adding no repeat after the URL but it is taking no effects. Below is my code;

```
    <style>
    body {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)), url("images/dms.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

I want to achieve something like the below code. I have the Image as a background which is not repeating and is centered.

```
    <style>
    body {
        background-image: url("images/dms.jpg");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: So, have you tried adding `background-size: cover;`, `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and `background-position: center center;`?

Comment: @Geshode Yes I have. No effect to the image but when I use the below code it is working

Comment: you need to add them after the background declaration

Comment: @codeninja I see. What you do in the gradient seems to only change the alpha, right? Maybe you can get your wanted result, by just using [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity). So, use the lower code and just add `opacity: 0.5;`.

Comment: @Geshode yes this solution worked. I also solved it by adding `!important` to the background properties while still using the gradient

Answer (score 0):

To make the body gradient, you should either set the `height` or you should
Set the `background-attachment` property to `fixed`

**solution 1 :**

```
    body {
        min-height:100vh;
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 
        1)), url("images/dms.jpg");
    }
```

**solution 2 :**

```
    body {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 
        1)), url("images/dms.jpg");
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

I solved it by adding the `!important` CSS rule to the backgound properties while still using the gradient like below;

```
body {
background-size: cover !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-position: center center !important;
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)), url("/images/dms.jpg");
}
```

Another way is to target the specific element and increase or decrease the opacity but you will have less control.

Comment: You have to use !important because you're using background shorthand. I guess if you try it with: background-image: url("/images/dms.jpg"), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50)); you don't have to use important...